# How to determine that reached the end of the list in listbox?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

How I can determine that reached the end of the list in listbox.

Comment: What exactly do you consider "reaching the end" ... are you paginating? Are you talking about a scrollbar reaching the end?

Comment: Yes, when i go to the bottom of scrollbar it should download some other items. How i can determine that moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListBox` has an `ScrollViewer` attached property which gives you access to the scroll functionality. Compare the `VerticalOffset` to the `ScrollableHeight`. If `VerticalOffset` == 0 then you're at the top of the `ListBox`. If `VerticalOffset` == `ScrollableHeight` then you are at the bottom of the ListBox. I would recommend adding this logic to the ScrollChanged handler.